# Troubleshooting wifi issues

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, xiaomi

Suddenly the wifi of my Xiaomi A1 stopped to connect my home's wifi :-/

There is no update, either phone or router, I'm aware off. But  at some point yesterday I realized I was not connected. So I tried to manually connect. First weird thing, Android doesn't have the password saved. I enter again the password, and I just get "failed to connect".

All the other devices (iphone, ipad, macbook, google home, chromecast, etc.) keep working as normal.

I've rebooted the router just in case, but no outcomes.

Any idea how can I troubleshoot that?

Comment: Have you also rebooted your phone?

Comment: Yes, I did that too.

Comment: It might be drastic but try to reset the network settings (found in Settings). Mobile & WiFi settings will be reset.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, with no results :-/

Comment: Create a hotspot on one of your other devices, and test if the xiaomi will be able to connect to it, to rule out a faulty WiFi chip

Comment: Damnit! It doesn't connect to that hotspot either... So the wifi chip has died. I'll try to make a hardware check.

Comment: This may be extreme but have you already tried a factory reset on your device?

Answer (score 0):

As discovered in the comments thread, my issue looks to be a hardware issue on the phone itself.